# Sorting json with jq

Tags: json, rest, sorting, parsing, jq

I have this json (simplified) coming from a REST api:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "run-bWSq4YeYpfrW4mx7",
      "type": "runs",
      "attributes": {
        "source": "tfe-configuration-version",
        "status": "planned",
        "status-timestamps": {
          "planned-at": "2017-11-28T22:52:51+00:00"
        }
    }
    },
    {
      "id": "run-bWSq4YeYpfrW4ft7",
      "type": "runs",
      "attributes": {
        "source": "tfe-configuration-version",
        "status": "planned",
        "status-timestamps": {
          "planned-at": "2017-11-28T21:52:51+00:00"
        }
    }
    }
    ]
}
```

How I can sort it based `status-timestamps.planned-at`?

Among other things I tried this `jq '[.data[].attributes | sort_by(.status-timestamps.planned-at) ]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this achieve what you wanted ?

```
jq '.data |= sort_by(.attributes."status-timestamps"."planned-at")'
```